# How to retain the mysqli_fetch_array() value in while loop?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I don't know if the question is clear enough from the title.

I'm fetching some IDs from table A and the query returns multiple rows. I'm also fetching some other IDs from other table B. My question is I want to check if the ID of table A is same as of the ID in table B, and if so I have to print a value else other value should be printed. How can I implement this?

I have tried using two while loops (one inside the other) but the inner while loop executes only one time and the value becomes null. So its unable to check the condition.

```
<?php
include('includes/template.php');
$user=$_SESSION['login_user'];

if(isset($_POST['action'])){
if($_POST['action']=="searchb"){
  $query=secure_input($_POST['searchbox']);
                  if(!empty($query)){
                    $sql="select id,username, name, email from mysql.registration_zany where name like '%".$query."' and privacy=0";
                          $res=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
                 $resmsg="<div class='alert alert-success' role='alert'>SEARCH RESULTS FOR :<b>".$query."</b></div>";
             }
      }
}
$sql2="select id from mysql.friends where id2='".$id."' and Request_Status=1 and id !=".$id;
$res2=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
$i=1;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_NUM)){
$flag=0;
  while($fr[i]=mysqli_fetch_array($res2,MYSQLI_NUM)){
    #echo $row[0];
if($fr[i][0]==$row[0]){
  $flag=1;
 }
  }
$i++;
if($flag){
$table="<div class='row'>
<div class='col-xs-6 col-md-4'>
  <div class='thumbnail'>
UserName:".$row[1]."<br>Profile:".$row[2]."<br>E-mail:".$row[3]."
<p><span class='label label-info'>Friend</span></p></div></div>";
echo $table;
}
else{
$table="<div class='row'>
<div class='col-xs-6 col-md-4'>
<div class='thumbnail'>
 UserName:".$row[1]."<br>Profile:".$row[2]."<br>E-mail:".$row[3]."
 <p><form action='request.php' method='post'>
 <input name='action' type='hidden' value='".$row[0]."' >
  <input type='submit' class='btn btn-primary' name='req' value='Send Request'>
  </form></p></div></div>";
 echo $table;
 }
  }
 ?>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The inner `while` loop becomes null and so its not checking the `if` condition inside it.

My suggestion is to use `mysqli_free_result();` and after that execute the sql statement outside the inner while loop.

```
mysqli_free_result($res2);
$sql2="select id from mysql.friends where id2='".$id."' and Request_Status=1  and id !=".$id;
$res2=mysqli_query($con,$sql2);
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

if I understand correctly,
You're looking to check each ID from the first table against every value in your second table?.

For simplicity sake I'll assume the tables exist on different servers and cannot be joined.

If you store all ID's to an array `$table1[] = $row['id'];`

You will be able to search using PHP's in_array function while going through t able 2.

`in_array($row['id'], $table1)` (True if value exists)

If you just want to know what exists in both tables however you can do this in your SQL. not knowing your database structure I'll do this loosely

```
$sql="SELECT
 q1.id,
 count(SELECT q2.id from mysql.friends q2 WHERE q2.id2=q1.id and Request_Status=1 and q2.id !=q1.id) as 'hasmatch',
 q1.username,
 q1.name,
 q1.email FROM mysql.registration_zany q1 WHERE q1.name LIKE '%".$query."' AND q1.privacy=0";
```

I would play with this a bit, I'm a little rusty and it may drop values that don't have a match. I'm hoping the count eliminates that problem.